# Approximation implies Homotopy

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ and $N$ be manifolds .I have recently stumbled upon the fact that if $f_n\rightarrow f$  in the strong topology $C_S^r(M,N)$, then we will have that there exists a subsequence of maps that are homotopic to $f$. After looking things up all the proofs that I found use tubular neighborhoods, things that I have yet not seen . Is there another way to prove this statement without using tubular neighborhoods ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $N$ has a lower bound in injectivity radius (for example when $N$ is comapct) then you can slide $f_n$ to $f$ along the minimal geodesic from $f_n(x)$ to $f(x)$.